# "Duplicate catch block #loc" in CoffeeScript in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, webstorm

This causes a red line (error) in IntelliJ but it compiles, what's the deal?

```
try
  doSomething () ->
    try
       foo()
    catch e
      handleError e 
catch e 
  handleError e
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's an error in webstorm, works correctly and compiles correctly.  The `try` blocks are necessary for each callback.